# What should I write in sendMessage method to show output on screen

Tags: android

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.surajchand.googlepro.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view){
        System.out.println("Hello Guys");

    }
}
```

Comment: I wish to print "Hello Guys". how to do that

Comment: Write `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello Guys", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to do?

```
Log.i("myMessage", "Hello Guys"); //display console output using log cat.
```

if u have something in your layout, for example a textview that you want to write.

Set id for textview, for example:  text_id

```
TextView myText = (TextView) findById(R.id.text_id);
myText.setText("Hello Guys");
```

Something like this:

```
public void sendMessage(View view){

   if( view instanceof TextView){
      TextView myText = (TextView) view;
      myText.setText("Hello Guys");
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can print with any of below way

Message in console:

```
Log.i("Your Message", "Hello Guys");
Log.d("Your Message", "Hello Guys");
```

Toast Message:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello Guys", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)This is your code.**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view){
        System.out.println("Hello Guys");

    }
}
```

2)Check Below Code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     TextView showoutput;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        showoutput=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.moutput);  
    }

     public void sendMethod(View v) {
        Log.e("Hello Guys", "Hello Guys");
        Log.d("Hello Guys", "Hello Guys");
        Log.v("Hello Guys", "Hello Guys");

// below snack bar show output on android device bottom side Time LENGTH_LONG and Length_SHORT

        Snackbar.make(v, "Hello Guys", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

// by using toast we can show toast message with Time LENGTH_LONG and Length_SHORT
        Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this, "Hello Guys", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

//In TextView also you can show error
    showoutput.setText("Hello guys");

```
    }
}
```

**3)In XML on Button click Code** 
    1)android:onClick="sendMethod" 
    2)in java with same name public void sendMethod(View v){

// Your code here
}

```
  <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Click here to show output on window and Logcat"
            android:onClick="sendMethod"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
```